# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory Play framework runs in Java

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

I have a application that runs in play framework. It works fine in local machine. I have configured application in CentOS Linx system. I have Unzipped the play package and put it into /var/lib/ directory. My application i put it into the directory /var/www/ directory.
While running the play dependencies in command it is showing the following error :

```
[root@xxxxxx004 InterShareServerHub]# /var/lib/play-1.2.5/play dependencies   ~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.5, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is sales-demo
~
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/play-1.2.5/play", line 153, in <module>
    status = cmdloader.commands[play_command].execute(command=play_command, app=play_app, args=remaining_args, env=play_env, cmdloader=cmdloader)
  File "/var/lib/play-1.2.5/framework/pym/play/commands/deps.py", line 55, in execute
    return_code = subprocess.call(java_cmd, env=os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I dont know how to solve this issue. I have set an path for java. Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is related to the Python subsystem of Play not locating Java correctly.

You say you have set the path to Java... so check that by opening a command prompt and executing the command:

```
java -version
```

If this indeed prints the Java version as expected, then print the path setting:

```
set path
```

This should have the path to Java somewhere in it. Now for the last step, see if you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set:

```
set java_home
```

For me, this printed a path that was not correct. Interestingly, Play! itself does not seem to use this setting, but it's Python subsystem apparently does. This can give you very strange behavior. If indeed java_home is set to a wrong path, you can probably remove it from the environment settings completely, but before doing so I recommend removing it just for the current CMD window, by executing:

```
set java_home=
```

Then, verify that it now works by running this command (in the same CMD window!):

```
play dependencies
```